# where are the vagrant api docs?

Tags: vagrant

Ruby has a comprehensive set of API docs, for example [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/).

Where are the API documents for Vagrant? The only thing I can find is the [code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant), but that isn't a substitute for API documents.

Comment: http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/ ???

Comment: I couldn't find any API information in those documents.  They seem to focus on the command line, rather than from a coding perspective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're looking for source code documentation, you can find it here:

http://rdoc.info/github/mitchellh/vagrant/frames

Anyway, Vagrant doesn't have a real API, but you can use *machine readable output* for interacting with it. More info here:

http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/machine-readable.html

Answer (score 1):

There are some docs [here](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/). Don't get confused. They are not for V2 but for the latest version.

Earlier versions of docs where deprecated and removed not to create confusion in search results.

Documentation as of now is really **small** and most of the time you'll need to check the **source** code

Comment: Ah, thanks.  It sounds like I need to spend some more time with the source code.

Comment: @SHC unfortunately yes. But don't forget that vagrant uses ruby so it's quite easy.

Comment: @SHC For the old docs that provide for info but obsolete http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/